# Created a python lottery draw using if elif else statements + import random choice

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, python-import

I have tried to create a lottery game in python by using import random choice and if, elif and else statements. I guess it is working as it should. How can I use a function to replicate this lottery game? Thanks

```
from random import choice  # import module

# I created a list of lottery numbers below:
lottery_numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
#  the person who gets this combinations of numbers and letters on the ticket wins
print("if the following numbers or letters are chosen \n"
      "the person  wins a prize: e, 1, b, 10 ")

if (choice(lottery_numbers)) == 'e':
    print("winner!!")
elif (choice(lottery_numbers)) == '1':
    print('winner!')
elif (choice(lottery_numbers)) == 'b':
    print("winner")
elif (choice(lottery_numbers)) == '10':
    print("winner")
else:

    print('you lose, next time!!')
```

Comment: By wrapping the code you've written inside of a function? You're gonna have to be a bit more specific about exactly what part you're struggling with.

Comment: hi, I intended to construct this lottery game in a way that by using the choice function if the four lottery numbers are selected together then the person wins, but I am not sure if I have done this properly by using elif else statements, I thing that maybe I could use a function: def , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
count = 0 
#this does the choice function four times and checks if the number variable is equal to one of the lottery values. If so, it increments count by 1

for i in range(4):
    number  = choice(lottery_numbers)
    if number == 'e' or number ==  '1' or number == 'b' or number == '10':
        count+=1

# count must = four because there are four lottery numbers
if count == 4:
    print('you won')

else:
    print('you lose')
```